# THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial clearcoatNormalMap RepeatWrapping

Tags: three.js

I'm just wondering if there is a way to get THREE.RepeatWrapping working with clearcoatNormalMap.
It works fine for the normalMap but appears not to tile when uses as a clearcoatNormalMap

Comment: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/18677#issuecomment-679160107

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply West Are there any known limitations apart from performance that is stopping repeat texturing of the clear coat normal?
I'm happy to have a look into it if you point me where to start.

Comment: You can follow the above link.